# Maintaining User Session (after Facebook O-Auth, Server-side-login)

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, oauth-2.0, session-cookies

I am writing a mobile app that uses O-Auth's "connect with Facebook" in order to:

```
1) Let Facebook deal with the authentication
2) Not force my users to register to another website
3) Get Facebook information
```

I have implemented Facebook's Server-side-login (in JAVA):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

I do not understand how do i maintain the user session once the user have connected-with-facebook.

Here is the flow from end-to-end, please correct me if i'm wrong.

```
1) The user logs into my server (Android APP using WebView)
2) The server redirect the user to Facebook (with client_id, redirect_url, state and permissions)
3) The user is now facing Facebook's login dialog.
  3.1) If the user deny: Facebook calls the redirect_url and notify the server that there was an error. (Flow Ends here)
  3.2) If the user accept: Facebook calls the redirect_url (my server) with the state i've set (for CSRF protection) and a code.
4) The server contacts Facebook and send it the app_id, redirect_url, client_secret and code and in return, facebook calls the redirect_url with a valid token. This token allows the server to issue facebook API calls on behalf of the user.
```

So far everything works great. Now to the main question - Session management.

Now that I got the token, I need to figure out to which user it belongs to, so I can grab data from my database or create a new entry (in case of a new user).

1) What kind of identifier should I use in order to identify the user in my server db? (Do I need to call Facebook API to retrieve basic information and from that extract the email and/or unique id?

2) Once I got this unique ID how do I contact the user again? At step 2 the server Redirected him to Facebook, which means that he opened a new connection to Facebook and he is no longer connected to the server. How do i set him a cookie now that's he's gone? <-- ****This part is the most confusing for me.****

3) At what point do i need to set a SESSION ID (cookie) on the user's Request so the next time he contacts me i'll know who it is.

I think that Stack overflow is the best example to illustrate my problem.
I clicked on "Connect with facebook" button, and suddenly i'm a user at Stack overflow without any registration. How does Stack overflow know how to pull the questions that i've already asked? How did it identified me? And at what point in the chain I've described did it set a cookie on my request ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

1. You've come across one of the basic misunderstandings about OAuth: OAuth is all about **authorization**. A user gives *you* (the *client*) the permission to access data on *his* behalf. If you want to **authenticate** a user, some providers allow you to access a **unique id** that allows you to distinguish users. So, yes, if you want to identify a user, you have to request his **unique id**.
2. There are multiple ways to do this. All of them are about generating a **unique session id** that you store **before** redirecting the user. Once the user comes back, he returns an **id** to you. If you see, that you issued and stored that **id**, you delete the **id** and you know to which user you are talking. You could either store this **id** in a cookie or hand it over as part of the `state` parameter.
3. Anytime before redirecting would be possible. If you want to know which user you are talking to anytime, just do this the first time he calls you.